# Topological/homotopical classification for 1-dim CW-complexes?

Tags: algebraic-topology, homotopy-theory, cw-complexes

It's a common exercise to classify a collection of 1-dim objects, say the figures of 0-9, or A-Z, up to homeomorphism or homotopy equivalence. I suddenly raise a question in general:

> Is there any systematical methods (or algorithms) to classify all 1-dim CW complexes? Or is it decidable/computable?

I googled but found no result on classifications for 1-dim CW complexes. It seems that 1-dim CW complexes are relatively simpler than higher dimensional ones, and it's closely related to graph theory. However, I cannot explicate a graph theoretical problem equivalent to this, or even give some ideas to proceed for the reduction. I need some help.

Any idea? Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In general, connected 1-D CW complexes, i.e. connected graphs, are classified up to homotopy by the abelian group rank of their first homology, equivalently the free group rank of their fundamental group. If the graph happens to be finite, or if its rank is finite, then the Euler characteristic works too.

To classify general 1-D CW complexes up to homotopy equivalence, one simply counts how many components there are for each possible value of the rank.

On the other hand, classifying connected finite graphs up to homeomorphism is a delicate combinatorial job. I do not believe there are any closed form expressions for the number of homeomorphism types of graphs of a given rank, say, although there may be generating functions.

**Additional remarks:** To respond to OP's clarification in the comments, one can reduce the graph homeomorphism classification to graph isomorphism classification in the following manner. This can be done for arbitrary graphs, but the statement is simpler for finite connected graphs which are not homeomorphic to the circle $S^1$ and I'll restrict to that situation. (Also, in my discussion graphs are not "simplicial complexes": an edge can have both ends attached to the same vertex, and two edges can have their respective ends attached to the same pair of vertices).

Consider a finite connected graph $G$ not homeomorphic to $S^1$. By removing the valence $2$ vertices of $G$ from the vertex set one gets another graph structure on $G$, which I like to think of as the "natural" graph structure on $G$ (this doesn't work if $G$ is a circle, or an infinite graph homeomorphic to $\mathbb{R}$, or an infinite graph with an isolated "end").

Then what one shows is the following:

- If two finite connected graphs $G,G'$ have no valence $2$ vertices then $G,G'$ are homeomorphic if and only if they are isomorphic as graphs.

As the OP says in his comment, the hard part is the "only if" direction. The main fact needed for the proof is that the valence of a point $p$ in a graph is a local topological invariant: the valence of $p$ is equal to the number of connected components of $U-p$ for all sufficiently small connected neighborhoods $U$ of $p$. Also, assuming $G$ has no valence $2$ vertices, the points of $G$ with valence $2$ are precisely the points in the interiors of edges, and the points with valence $\ne 2$ are precisely the vertices. Putting this together, if $G,G'$ have no valence $2$ vertices then any homeomorphism $f : G \mapsto G'$ restricts to a bijection of vertices, and a bijection of edges that preserves endpoints, and so $f$ is a graph isomorphism.

I like to use this discussion as one of the first applications of connectivity in my algebraic topology course.

Comment: I doubt the homeo. cls. is related to graph isomorphism problem somewhat, so maybe undecidable.

Comment: @FrankScience: If you can enumerate finite graphs up to graph isomorphism, then you can enumerate finite graphs up to homeomorphism by throwing out all graphs that have a vertex of valence 2.

Comment: But then are non-graph-isomorphic thrown graphs non-homeomorphic? I guess so but I cannot conceive a proof.

Comment: Every graph that has vertices of valence 2  (and is not homeomorphic to the circle) is homeomorphic to the graph obtained by removing each valence 2 vertex from the vertex set.

Comment: Yes, but when they are removed, I cannot see any reason that two *non-isomorphic* graphs are *not* homeomorphic.

Comment: I guess I'm not quite sure about your concern. Suppose you have two finite, connected graphs $G_1,G_2$, neither a circle, and you then change the graph structures on $G_1,G_2$ by removing the valence 2 vertices from the vertex set, obtaining new graphs $G'_1,G'_2$ without valence 2 vertices. The graphs $G_1,G'_1$ are homeomorphic to each other, as are the graphs $G_2,G'_2$. One thing which is true here is that $G'_1,G'_2$ are homeomorphic if and only if they are graph isomorphic. Is that what you are asking about?

Comment: Yes, and in fact, the *if* part is tautological, so we only need to tackle with the *only if* part.

Comment: @FrankScience: I augmented my answer to address this issue.

Comment: Very good. Thanks!

Answer (score 4):

Well, 1-dimensional CW complexes are graphs, and every (connected) graph is homotopically equivalent to a wedge sum of circles. Hence they are classified by their $\pi_1$ (actually just their Euler characteristic is sufficient if they are finite).

For details see Hatcher - Algebraic Topology (http://www.math.cornell.edu/~hatcher/AT/AT.pdf), sections 1.A and 1.B.

Comment: Thanks. I do have Hatcher but I didn't read it. Any idea on topological classification?

Comment: I don't know but I found these notes: http://www.math.ens.fr/~bessis/m2.pdf . "Up to homotopy equivalence of their geometric realizations, connected graphs are only determined by their “number of independent cycles” (first Betti number). By contrast, the classification of graphs up to homeomorphism of their geometric realizations is very complicated (it is essentially the same as classifying them up to isomorphism)."

Comment: The difference between graph-iso and homeo is that intuitively we can merge two adjacent edges and delete the joint vertex if it's only connected with these edges. It's inequivalent, but to my intuition, it could be shown that homeo problem is somewhat no easier than graph-iso problem.

Comment: Yes it should be so, and I think it is also the point of that comment in those notes.